Families of $4$-subsets with small intersection
Consider this MSE question which has following setup: We have a set $X$ with cardinality $= n$ and a family $\mathcal{F}$ of $4-$subsets of $X$ such that for two distinct $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$, $|A\cap B| \leq 1$. How large can such a family be? The answer given there implies an upper bound of $1 + n + \binom{n}{2}$ using a much more general theorem of Frankl and Wilson. How can we directly prove a quadratic (perhaps improved) upper bound?
For a lower bound, the best I can do is a simple $n^2/16$ bound: Let $X = [n]$ and for $l(x) = ax + b$, define the set $S_{l}$ to be $\{l(0), l(1), l(2), l(3)\}$. Then the family $\mathcal{F} = \{S_{ax+b}|a, b \in [n/4]\}$ satisfies the intersection condition because two lines can only meet at a single point, and $\mathcal{F}$ has size $n^2/16$.

The $\mathcal{F}$ defined in the second part is actually a family (two different lines correspond to distinct sets of points), because the slopes are all positive.

Optimal values for small $n$ are here: https://oeis.org/A004037

This answer is helpful.

Your upper bound is the best possible, asymptotically. I will show how to achieve your bound exactly when $n=4^k$, for some $k\in \mathbb N$. Afterwords, I give some citations that deal with the other $n$.
First, consider a harder problem. The condition $|A\cap B|\le 1$ means that each pair of elements of $X$ appear together in at most one subset. For which $n$ can we find a family of $4$-element subsets of $X$ such that every pair of elements of $X$ appears together in exactly one subset? Such a family is known as a balanced incomplete block design, and is denoted $\mathrm{BIBD}(n,4,1)$. Necessarily, the number of blocks here must be $\binom{n}2/\binom{4}2$, so this design solves your problem optimally.

Lemma: For all $n\in \mathbb N$, if  a $\mathrm{BIBD}(n,4,1)$ exists, then a $\mathrm{BIBD}(4n,4,1)$ exists.

Proof: $\newcommand\s{\spadesuit}
\newcommand{\h}{\heartsuit}
\newcommand{\c}{\clubsuit}
\newcommand{\d}{\diamondsuit}$ Let $\mathcal B$ be a collection of size-$4$ subsets of $[n]$. I will show how to construct a collection $\mathcal C$ of size-$4$ subsets of $\{\s,\h,\c,\d\}\times [n]$. To do this, I will use a pair of orthogonal Latin squares $L$ and $M$ of side width $n$. Such an $L,M$ exists for all $n$ except $2$ and $6$, but a $\mathrm{BIBD}(n,4,1)$ does not exist when $n\in\{2,6\}$, anyway.
For each $B\in \mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$ contains the sets $B\times \{\s\},B\times \{\h\},B\times \{\c\}$, and $B\times \{\d\}$. Furthermore, for each $i,j\in [n]$, $\mathcal C$ contains the set $$\{(\s,i),(\h,j),(\c,L_{i,j}),(\d,M_{i,j})\}$$
You can use the definition of orthogonal Latin squares to show that every pair of elements of $\{\s,\h,\c,\d\}\times [n]$ occurs in exactly one of the sets described. $\tag*{$\square$}$
Now, by repeatedly applying this lemma, you get that a $\mathrm{BIBD}(4^k,4,1)$ exists for all $k\in \mathbb N$. Therefore, the bound of $\binom n2/\binom 42$ is achieved infinitely often.
In fact, the bound is correct up to an additive factor. As shown in the CRC Handbook of Combinatorial Designs (Theorem $40.12$), for all $n\ge 4$,
$$
\exists \mathcal F:\quad |\mathcal F|
\ge \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}3\right\rfloor\right\rfloor-3.
$$ However, the constructions which prove this are quite involved, so I will not show them here. For constructions in the case when $n\equiv 1$ or $4\pmod{12}$, see the paper by Hannani cited below. In these cases, Hanani constructs a $\mathrm{BIBD}(n,4,1)$.  Finally, you may be interested in the Rodl paper below, which shows how to achieve $(1+o(1))\cdot \binom{n}2/\binom{4}2$ using the probabilistic method.

Charles J. Colbourn and Jeffrey H. Dinitz. 2006. Handbook of Combinatorial Designs, Second Edition (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications). Chapman & Hall/CRC.
H. Hanani, Balanced incomplete block designs and related designs, Discrete Math. 11
(1975) 255–369. https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(75)90040-0
Vojtěch Rödl, On a Packing and Covering Problem, European Journal of Combinatorics, Volume 6, Issue 1, 1985, 69-78, ISSN 0195-6698, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(85)80023-8.


There seems to be a simple upper bound of $n^2/12$: If $\{S_1, \ldots, S_m\}$ is the family then $m\binom{4}{2}\leq \binom{n}{2}$ because the sets of 2-subsets of the $S_j$'s must disjoint.
